# Why $N= \max(2,\frac {2}{\epsilon})$ for $|a_n -L|<\epsilon $ convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=\dfrac{\sin(n)}{n^2 - 2}$. I am studying the proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. By definition:

> For every $\epsilon  \in \mathbb{R}^+$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N $

Can anyone tell me why in the process of proof one uses   $N = \max (2,\frac {2}{\epsilon})$. How is this obtained?

When I worked on this, I reduced the inequality $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$  to $\frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon$ after estimating $\sin$ by $ 1$.

Why was I incorrect to estimate $\sin (n)$ by $1$? More importantly, may you list the steps to get $N = \max (2,\frac {2}{\epsilon})$

Comment: Please add more context. What is $a_n$? Where are you getting $N=$ whatever.

Comment: This is from a formula that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N>0$ such that $|a_n -L|<  \epsilon$ for all $n>N$ however I'm new to the max (-,-) notation and cannot understand the estimation steps used to get to this answer for N.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you so much. May you start from the original $|a_n -L|$ and perform your steps from that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have $2n^2-4>n$ when $n\ge 2$.  This implies that

$$\left|\frac{1}{n^2-2}\right|<\frac{2}{n}$$

whenever $n\ge 2$.  If we let $N=\max\left(2,\frac{2}{\epsilon}\right)$, then we must have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\sin (n)}{n^2-2}-0\right|&\le\left|\frac{1}{n^2-2}-0\right|\\\\
&<\frac{2}{n}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>N$.  And we are done!

Comment: How do you know to start from :  $2n^2-4>n$.  And to compare it to $\frac{2}{n}$? I can see now why. N=2 because of the denominator, but the other steps are a minor mystery.

Comment: @Forever_A_Student Well, we could develop a more complicated form for $N$ such as $N=\max(2,\sqrt{2+1/\epsilon})$.  But, keeping things simple is usually better.  So, we look at $n^2-2$ and note that this is bigger than $n/2$ provided $n\ge 2$.  But we need the maximum of $2$ and something since $1^2-2<0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful. May you start from the original $|a_n -L|$ and perform your steps from that point? Also seeing I have an exam on these topics in an hour may you answer a few of my other unanswered questions? (I hope that's not an inappropriate request)

Comment: @Forever_A_Student  You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Yes, you can start from the original inequality.  We actually did that after a little introduction to show the validity of the steps.

Comment: Also seeing I have an exam on these topics in an hour may you answer a few of my other unanswered questions? (I hope that's not an inappropriate request)

Comment: I understand it now. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Forever_A_Student No worry.  I enjoyed helping.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: That was an error. I tried to make it an up vote but it changed to -1.  It's now neutral. Apologies. Your attitude towards helping others is commendable.